# Disable the table view reloading while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on a chatting application. I don't want to reload the `tableview` when scrolling.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        @try {

            static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cell";
            MessageCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            if(cell==nil)
            {
                cell=[[MessageCell alloc]initMessagingCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            }
            if(self.check)
            {
                cell.sent=YES;
                cell.messageLabel.text=[self.sendArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            }
            else
            {
                cell.sent=NO;
                cell.messageLabel.text=[self.sendArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            }
            cell.timeLabel.text=@"27-04-2016";
            cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            return cell;
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Error in func:%s, line:%d with reason:%@",__func__,__LINE__,exception.reason);

        }

}
```

When I send the message it shows on the right(`self.check` is `YES`), and when I receive the message it shows on the left (`self.check` is `NO`) but the problem is when I'm `scrolling`, the `tableview` reloads itself and shows the entire message (either send or received) on the left because `self.check` is `NO`.

How can I stop this happening?

Comment: self.check should be an array and it should be a specific value for each row. You could check it like: if(self.check[indexPath.row])

Comment: self.check is a BOOL which only find that message is send or received.

Comment: yes, but you said self.check is always NO, that's is because it looks like you have not checking your self.check. You should either check your self.check each time cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called, or have an array of self.check with the specific value for each row.

Comment: yes sir, I got it.

Comment: @J. Lopes Thank you.. I solved the issue

Comment: Oh that's great! How did you solve it?

Comment: @J.Lopes I allocate a array and check the array according your statement if(self.check[indexPath.row]) ... Thank u Sir :)

Comment: I created a answer. Could you please vote it as the answer? So your question will be closed with an right answer. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self.check should be an array and it should be a specific value for each row. So you could check it like:

```
if(self.check[indexPath.row]) {
    // Do something!
}
```

I'm glad this has helped you.

Answer (score 1):

In your MessageCell class, you have to override prepareForReuse() method and reset all flags.
When we scroll tableview it reuses the constructed cells. Therefore, it also reuses the flags. Here is the example

```
override func prepareForReuse() 
{
    super.prepareForReuse();
    currencyCodeLbl.text = nil;
    currencyNameLbl.text = nil;
    isSelf = false;
    flagImage.hnk_cancelSetImage();
    flagImage.image = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should create a instance property to keep track of the tableView state. Based on the value of this property you can either reload or not reload your table view (wherever in your code you're doing this).

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isTableViewScrolling;
```

To keep track if someone is dragging/scrolling the tableview you can use the scrollView delegate methods:

```
scrollViewWillBeginDragging:

scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:
```

and set `isTableViewScrolling` accordingly